# What key presses are required to exit Grand Theft Auto V on PC?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I'm a totally blind player of GTA V, and up until now when quitting the game have done so by killing the executable process directly via the Task Manager - however, it appears that there is also the option of quitting the game from within the pause menu (via the "Game" submenu). If it's not too much trouble, would somebody be able to give me the exact keys that I need to press to reach this icon - in terms of the arrow keys that I need to press?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alt+F4 works, and brings a menu asking if you're sure you want to quit. Pressing Enter quits the game at that point.

Otherwise, you can open the menu, navigate towards "Exit Game" to bring up that same menu, and once again, press Enter to quit.

Comment: I think Elliott wants to know the exact keypress count.

Comment: I didn't realise that pressing alt-F4 displayed an overlay - doing this and then hitting enter works. Thank you. :)